# Dynamically change background color of mat-expansion-panel-header based on whether or not it is expanded

Tags: html, css, angular, material-design, angular6

I've been struggling to find a way to dynamically change the background color of a material design expansion panel header based on whether or not the panel is expanded.

When the panel is closed I'd like the background color to be white, but when it is expanded I want to change that color to something else. I'm not seeing something I can base this change off of, maybe I'm missing something. I'm new to angular and was thinking I would just be able to base it off of [expanded]'s setting but it appears that is not the case.

```css
mat-accordion
mat-expansion-panel
mat-expansion-panel-header
mat-expanded{
  font-size: 1.25em;
  background-color: white;
  background: white;
  color: #00838f;
  font-weight: 500;
}



mat-accordion
mat-expansion-panel
mat-expansion-panel-header {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  background-color: white;
  background: white;

  color: #00838f;
  font-weight: 500;
}


  mat-accordion
  mat-expansion-panel
  .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
  color: #00838f;
}
```

```html
<mat-accordion multi="true">
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="selectedBenefitCategories.indexOf(cat)!=-1" [hidden]="selectedBenefitCategories.indexOf(cat)===-1">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <i class="search-category-icon far fa-star"></i> &nbsp; {{cat}}
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>

    some content

  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Angular Material does add dynamic classes based on the `expanding` state.

`mat-expanded` would be the one you are looking for. The problem is this class gets also attached to the panel-content. In order to fix this, you can simply combine it with the `.mat-expansion-panel-header` class selector.

All summed up this would look like this:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded {
  background: red;
}
```

> Notice: Angular Material does also add `background: inherit` on the hover state.

If that's not the behavior you want, simply overwrite it like this:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded,
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I missed something here but I had to use `.mat-expansion-panel` and not header for it to work. Otherwise, it would highlight the previous expanded panel/header for a split second when expanding other ones. Still upvoted both because it led me in the right direction.

Comment: @codeMagic Hey, Thanks for the hint! It could be that something changed, I will check it soon and update it.

Comment: .mat-expansion-panel.mat-expanded .mat-expansion-panel-header { ... } works for me

Answer (score 5):

You have to provide a CSS selector that is stronger than the default ones that are provided by angular material. This means including all the states where angular adds `background-color: inherit`:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded,
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded:hover,
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: +1 This works for the expanded state. It does not work when hovering for the collapsed one.
Like: `.mat-expansion-panel-header,
.mat-expansion-panel-header:hover,
.mat-expansion-panel-header:focus {
    background-color: red;
}`

Answer (score 1):

### On  @angular/material version +10

add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` into @Component

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Then any CSS will work normally

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded,
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded:hover,
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your CSS file, it will add red color background to expansion panel header when the expansion panel is in expanded state.

```
.mat-expansion-panel.mat-expanded .mat-expansion-panel-header{
     background: red;
}
```