# mat-expansion-panel-header background-color on collapse

Tags: html, css, angular

i have some mat-expansion-panels. The header should have a specified color. Ok so on.. but when i expand the Panel, the color changes back to the root color...

[image]

How can i change this?

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header [expandedHeight]="'50px'"  [collapsedHeight]="'50px'" id="test1">

    <mat-panel-title>
        <div class="matPanelSceneSymbol"><i class="material-icons md-36 md-light active">weekend</i></div>

        <div class="matPanelSceneText"> Testszene</div>
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      <div class="matPanelSceneText">Szenenbeschreibung</div>
    </mat-panel-description>

  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

.....
....

css

```css
/deep/ .mat-expansion-panel-header{
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 1px !important;
//  background-color: #0070c040  !important;
    padding-bottom: 1px !important;
}

/deep/ .mat-expansion-panel-header .mat-expanded{
    background-color: none;
}

#test1{
    background-color:  #0070c040  !important;
}

#test2{
    background-color:  #8e0fbc40  !important;
}
```

Comment: Please try:
.mat-expansion-panel-content, .mat-expansion-panel {
    background: #7acc60;
}

Comment: nope.. this will color my hole content. I will just the header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` into @Component

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Then CSS will work fine

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded,
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Worked on **@angular/material version +10**

Comment: It is very wrong to use None ViewEncapsulation as it will affect the styles of the whole application

Comment: @SachithRukshan what other solution could we do?

Comment: the best solution would be to add these kind of styles in a global stylesheet like style.scss, while selecting a specific class. another solution would be to use ng-deep, but you need to be highly cautious when using it as it has some consequences.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ViewEncapsulation.None use ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom. It will not override global styles.

```
@Component({
...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

LESS:

```
.bgcolor{
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded,
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded:hover {
   background: red;
 }}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-accordion>
 <mat-expansion-panel class="bgcolor">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>...</<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-description>...</<mat-panel-description>
 </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515461/dynamically-change-background-color-of-mat-expansion-panel-header-based-on-wheth/50515881).

You just need to add css for the expanded state too:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded,
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded:hover {
  background: #0070c040;
}
```

Needs a bit of tweaking on hover and expanding, but this should start anyone else that finds this off.

Comment: My mat-header shows root colour of white when the header is collapsed. Any solution for this please

Comment: You should post a new question showing your code.